# Fluent NHibernate mapping to Oracle 11G and SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, oracle11g, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

On an already in place table in the database we are trying to Add a column for the CreationDate

```
mapping.Map(x => x.CreationDate)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Default("to_date('01-01-0001','dd-MM-yyyy')")
```

This works perfectly fine with oracle but SQLite will not understand this, which is perfectly normal because it does not know the to_date() function.

If i use

```
DateTime.MinValue.ToString()
```

for the Default value with or without an specific format. Then it will work in SQLite but it wont work in Oracle.

Does someone know a solution to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leave out the defaultvalue and write a convention

```
class CreationDateConvention  : IPropertyConvention
{
    public CreationDateConvention(string default)
    {
        _default = default;
    }

    public void Apply(... instance)
    {
        if (instance.Name == "CreationDate")
            instance.Default(_default)
    }
}


// and while configuring
...FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<>().Conventions.Add(new CreationDateConvention(isOracle ? "to_date..." : Datetime.Minvalue.ToString())
```